# AngularJS filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to write the todo mvc application in angular but I have got stuck with the filtering. What I am trying to filter is todos which are completed/Active or show all. I have a variable that is called isCompleted which I'm trying to filter by. The strange thing is that it seems to work when I filter to get the completed but when I try to show the Active it shows both Active and completed. I have been trying to set data-ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: {isComplete: false}" but it still shows all my todos. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
<section id="main" data-ng-cloak="">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-all" data-ng-model="toggleAll" data-ng-click="markAll(toggleAll)" />
<ul id="todo-list">
    <li data-ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: selectFilter()" data-ng-class="{completed: todo.isCompleted}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" data-ng-model="todo.isCompleted" />
        <label>{{todo.title}}</label>
        <button class="destroy" data-ng-click="removeTodo(todo)"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
function TodosController($rootScope, $scope, $location) {

$scope.location = $location;
$scope.$watch('location.path()', function (path) {
    $scope.selectFilter = function () {
        if (path == '/active') {
            return { isCompleted: false };
        }
        else if (path == '/completed') {
            return { isCompleted: true };
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        } 

    };
});

if (!$rootScope.todos) {
    $rootScope.todos = [{ title: "todo1", isCompleted: true }, { title: "todo3", isCompleted: true }, { title: "todo2", isCompleted: false }];
    //$rootScope.todos = [new Todo('Todo1', true), new Todo('Todo4', true), new Todo('Todo2', true), new Todo('Todo3', false)];
}
...
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works as a charm for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `<li>`, add

```
ng-show="toggleAll || todo.isCompleted"
```

This means when `toggleAll` is checked, then it shortcut the `isComplete` and returns `true` for each item; if `toggleAll` is not checked, then whether to show depends on `isComplete`.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGgRJ/)**</kbd>